Re-run kubernetes job manually (NOT a cronjob)
In my kubernetes cluster i have 3 following jobs:
kubectl get jobs
NAME                         COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job1                         1/1           3m48s      25d
job2                         1/1           7s         25d
job3                         1/1           5s         12h

I would like to run manually job1.
I tired this:
kubectl get  jobs job1 -o yaml > job1-rerun.yaml
kubectl apply -f job1-rerun.yaml
Warning: resource jobs/job1 is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.

I think this didnt work.
Question:
How can i re-run kubernetes job manually?

No. There is definitely no way to rerun a kubernetes job unless you delete it first. As you are trying to reapply the yaml file which will not apply so you need to delete the job first.
Using following methods you can do this:
Method:1

Get yaml file of the existing job:
kubectl get job <job_name> -o yaml > <job_name>.yaml


Delete the existing job:
kubectl delete job <job_name>


Run the job again:
kubectl apply -f <job_name>.yaml



Method:2
Open the job1-rerun.yaml file in a text editor and make the following changes:

Remove the status section from the YAML file, as it contains information about the previous job run.

Change the name field to a new name for the new job instance, for example, job1-rerun.

The spec section should not be changed.


For more information go through this Document.

Thanks for reply,
I followed method 1.
However, i had to remove labels and selectors from the job YAML body (as it was giving selector not auto-generated error).
Once removed, job was applied without any warnings/errors. Yet the POD that was created out of this job is in Init:0/1 status (it has been like that for last 18 min).

Please share your YAML file will try to reproduce it meanwhile try method 2.

Please share your YAML file will try to reproduce it.
